# Ask the encoding of Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, unicode

I need to use some UTF8 characters in the String in some java files. I think I need to change the encoding of file to UTF8 Eclipse for them to work.

I would like to know how to set the default encoding to UTF8?

also, I would like to ask , after setting the encoding to UTF8, will the actual physical java file contains the UTF8 BOM header.

Comment: Hopefully interesting: [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html). Note that [UTF-8 recommends against the use of a BOM because a byte-stream does not have an "endianness"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse, go to `Preferences>General>Workspace` and select `UTF-8` as the Text File Encoding.

This should set the encoding for all the resources in your workspace. Any components you create from now on using the default encoding should all match.

Comment: You can also set project specific encoding settings. Select your project, right-click, `Properties > Resource > Text file encoding > Other`